# How to add the widgets manually to the sidebar?

Tags: widgets

How can I add the widget manually in the code ?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the **[`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)** function. The first argument is required. It is the PHP class name of the widget. For example:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <?php the_widget('WP_Widget_Search') ?>
</div>
```

You can also pass on extra arguments:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <?php the_widget('WP_Widget_Text', 'title=Hello&text=World') ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your call to `dynamic_sidebar()` is setup, you should be able to drop them in before or after the function. For example:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar">
        <!-- Your Widget Here -->
        <?php dynamic_sidebar(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can put your widget (as an `<li>` in this case) right in there and voilà!

Comment: can I call any widget manually? e.g <?php word_tube_widget(); ?>