# Enumerating over a category of links

Tags: links, customization, bookmark

I need to show a list of links, similar to what "Bookmarks" widget does.

But Bookmarks widget is not suitable, because I need to display links (with removed "http://") instead of titles and also images of a custom size. Bookmarks widget seems not to being able to do this.

As such, I want to code it in PHP.

My question: How to enumerate all links of a specified category?

Answer (score 1):

## Recycle the core

You could simply take the widgets code from core <sup>1)</sup>, rename the class and such and alter it to your needs. **OR** you could simply `extend` the core widget class and just alter what you need changed (overwrite the methods in your extending Widget class).

Than add a plugin comment on top and activate it.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Link Widget
 * Description: Altered from WP Core.
 * Version:     0.1
 * Required:    3.3
 * Author:      Your Name <mail@example.com>
 * Author URI:  http://example.com
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
```

[image]

<sup>1) The core widget you can [find here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.3/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L85).</sup>

Comment: This could probably be used to solve your other problem: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44903/should-use-widgets-in-this-case